# Pull JQuery array items to div tags in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I have three div tags right here

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

and i want to throw the values of this array into these divs

```
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

Final output will be this

```
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
```

Is this possible with JQuery or normal javascript?

Answer (score 5):

Use the each function to iterate over the set of divs.  The index parameter to the function can be used to pull the appropriate value from the array and assign it as the content of the div.

```
$('div').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).html(myArray[idx]);
});
```

Note I haven't included any bounds checking on the array or specifically limited which divs I'm dealing with.  Adjust the content of the function if you need to make sure that the index is within the bounds of the array.  Adjust the selector, using a class, for example, if you need to restrict the set of divs chosen.

Comment: super impressive tvanfosson, cleared up everything...thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  for(var ctr = 0; ctr < myArray.length ; ctr++){
    $('div:eq('+ ctr +')').text(myArray[ctr]);
  }
});
```

To select an indexed element http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwh8a/

Comment: Good job with the fiddle, but [please do not give link-only answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).